# using a sparql query as a building block in another query

Tags: sparql, fuseki

I can write a SPARQL query to concat words in a sentence found in individual triples to a single sentence:

```
SELECT  ?sent   (sample (?sf1) as ?sf11) (group_concat(?wf)  as ?sf2)  
WHERE 
{   ?sent a nlp:Sentence .
    {select *
    { ?w rdfs:partOf ?sent . 
      ?w a nlp:Token .
      ?w nlp:wordForm ?wf . 
    }   order by ?w 
  }
}  group by ?sent   
  limit 20
```

but I cannot find a way to use this select statement in another query, where I find the sentence `?sent` and would like to insert this select statement:

```
select * 
where  
{   ?tok a wn:Locomote. 
    ?tok nlp:lemma3 ?lem .
    ?tok rdfs:partOf ?sent .
    ?sent a nlp:Sentence .     
    ?werk ^rdfs:partOf ?sent . 
    {SELECT ?sent  (group_concat(?wf)  as ?sf2)  
    WHERE 
    {   ?sent a nlp:Sentence .
        {select *
        { ?w rdfs:partOf ?sent . 
          ?w a nlp:Token .
          ?w nlp:wordForm ?wf . 
        }   order by ?w 
      }
    }  group by ?sent  
  }
}
```

The result is a not the sentence found in the first part, but it seems as `?sent` in the nested query is not restricted by the outer query. 
I do not see how to nest properly. 
Thank you for help!

Comment: Please proofread your second query: **1.)** You are grouping by `?s` which is nowhere in the most inner query  –> this should for sure be `?sent` . In addition, I don't understand why you need the most inner query, `ORDER BY` will be lost by SPARQL semantics. **2.)** You're not selecting any variable `?sent` in the "middle query but just the aggregate `SELECT      (group_concat(?wf)  as ?sf2) ` -> so what should be joined here with the outer query?

Comment: Thank you for your observations. ad 1) this is a spelling error I introduced while making the case easier to report. I edited the original. ad 2) I did not understand that I should select the ?sent variable to join with the outer query. I edited the query and it now produces the desired result.  regarding the order clause: it is indeed not having an effect but I worry that the result could contain the words in arbitrary order. How can i assure the order?

Comment: You can't ensure this for `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Its input is a *multiset*, thus, at least by SPARQL semantics, no order can be guaranteed. It might happen that some triple store keep track of the order by implementation design, i.e. the underlying datastructures. But that's just by chance.

Comment: As you're using Jena, you could write your own custom aggregate function.

Comment: I tried to find documentation about how I should do this, but could find only documentation for building filter extension, which is not what is needed here. Could you point me to the right documentation and perhaps an example?

Comment: I put the example implementation into an answer below. It shows how to use it from Java. You still have to make Fusekei know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Example of custom aggregate in Jena:

```java
package org.stackoverflow.jena.customaggregate;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.logging.LogCtl;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Graph;
import org.apache.jena.query.*;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.binding.Binding;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.Expr;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.ExprEvalException;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.ExprList;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.NodeValue;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.aggregate.Accumulator;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.aggregate.AccumulatorFactory;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.aggregate.AggCustom;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.aggregate.AggregateRegistry;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.function.FunctionEnv;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.NodeConst;
import org.apache.jena.sparql.sse.SSE;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class AggGroupConcatSorted {
    static {
        LogCtl.setCmdLogging();
    }

    static AccumulatorFactory accumulatorFactory = (agg, distinct) -> new AccGroupConcatSorted(agg);

    static class AccGroupConcatSorted implements Accumulator {
        private AggCustom agg;

        private List<String> nodeStrList = new ArrayList<>();

        AccGroupConcatSorted(AggCustom agg) {
            this.agg = agg;
        }

        @Override
        public void accumulate(Binding binding, FunctionEnv functionEnv) {
            ExprList exprList = agg.getExprList();
            for (Expr expr : exprList) {
                try {
                    NodeValue nv = expr.eval(binding, functionEnv);
                    // Evaluation succeeded, add string to list
                    nodeStrList.add(nv.asString());
                } catch (ExprEvalException ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public NodeValue getValue() {
            // sort list
            Collections.sort(nodeStrList);
            // return single node which in fact is the concatenated string of the list elements
            return NodeValue.makeString(Joiner.on(" ").join(nodeStrList));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example aggregate that concatenates the node values in sorted order
        String aggUri = "http://example.org/group_concat_sorted" ;

        // register the custom aggregate - returns unbound for no rows
        AggregateRegistry.register(aggUri, accumulatorFactory, NodeConst.nodeMinusOne);

        // sample data
        Graph g = SSE.parseGraph("(graph (:s :p \"b\") (:s :p \"bc\") (:s :p \"abc\"))") ;
        String qs = "SELECT (<http://example.org/group_concat_sorted>(?o) AS ?x) {?s ?p ?o}" ;

        // query execution
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(qs) ;
        try ( QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(g)) ) {
            ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect() ;
            ResultSetFormatter.out(rs);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is very interesting but very new to me and I have to study... it is probably solving not only the current problem but may be a solution in other aspects of my application!